# String formatting with left zero padding

Tags: python, string, formatting

I would like to format a string with dynamically changing left zero padding depending on the value input to the string. Something like this:

```
value = 123
n=6
print("{value:0n}".format(value=value, n=n))
    '000123'
```

But I can't quite get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `str.zfill`:

```
print(str(value).zfill(n))
```

Output:

```
000123
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```py
f'%0{n}d' % value  # python >= 3.6
```